# DNS issue - Windows Domain Controller 2016 - Unable to resolve public and private hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, domain-controller, windows-server-2016, reverse-dns

I have configured a Domain Controller on a Windows Server 2016 (in AWS). Before setting up the AD I can able to browse the internet. But after configured the AD I can't able to ping the computers which all are added to that domain(but if I use FQDN its working). Also, I can't able to access the internet. But whenever I tried to ping using IP address I can able to access them. Public websites also.

- My windows domain name: sql.com
- I tried to add the 8.8.8.8 in the forwarders - Able to access all the websites.
- In Append this DNS suffix I added sql.com - Able to ping all the computers using their name.

## Network Settings:

1. VPC range: `172.31.0.0/16`
2. In DC DNS IP in IPv4 properties: `127.0.0.1`
3. Domain name: `sql.com`
4. Reverse lookup: `created (PTR records are also there)`
5. In AWS my AD and other servers are in public subnet. Necessary ports are opened.

## My Questions:

1. Why I couldn't able to ping the servers using their names (before adding the Append DNS suffix).
2. Why I couldn't able to access the internet (until I have added the 8.8.8.8 to the DNS forwarders.)
3. If I removed the google DNS IP from the forwarders and removed Append DNS suffix, after reboot the Network shows Public Network instead of a domain network.

Can anyone help me to understand at least first 2 questions,But Im using Windows Server 2012 from past few years where I didn't face any issues like this.

Comment: I have identified the issue, Its only in AWS, please never mind.

Comment: If you've solved, the issue, you can post an answer. Or you can delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have blogged it.
The issue with DNS server's forwarders and DNS suffix in IP properties. It won't automatically add these things in windows server 2016.

http://www.sqlgossip.com/windows-server-2016-in-aws-unable-to-resolve-public-and-local-dns/